# How do I make my makefile create a second executable?

Tags: c++, makefile

```
all:  exe1 exe2

exe1: obj1
     g++ -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 program1.o -o program1  -lgtest

obj1:
     g++ -c -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 program1.cc

exe2: obj2
     g++ -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 program2.o -o program2

obj2:
     g++ -c -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 program2.cc

clean:
     rm *.o *.exe
```

When I run the makefile, only target exe1 is compiled and created into an executable. If I make the target just exe2, I get the error message

```
make: Nothing to be done for `all'.
```

How do I make exe2 visible to the makefile?

Comment: All your actual Makefile target names are phony. There's nothing in the build instructions that creates executables whose actual filenames are `exe1` and `exe2`, which are linked from object module files named `obj1` and `obj2`. It's either that, or the shown Makefile is not the real Makefile, but a fake Makefile with made-up filenames. In either case, no dependencies are declared on source files at all, which is another problem. To summarize: fix target names, and declare dependencies on the source files. See the make man page for more info.

Comment: `obj1` needs to depend on `program1.cc`, but no such dependency is listed.   The fact that the `g++` command mentions `program1.cc` does not tell make that `obj1` depends on `program1.cc`.  Similarly for `obj2`.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html
This is exactly what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

The makefile should probably look more like this:

```
# Set the dependencies to the names of the executables you
# want to build
all:  program1 program2

#
# Make uses some variables to define tools.
# The most important for you is CXX: Which is set to the C++ compiler.

#
# Notice that target name should match the executable name.
#     This is because `make` will check its existence and creation date
#     against its dependenc(ies) existence and creation date.
program1: program1.o
     $(CXX) -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 program1.o -o program1  -lgtest

program2: program2.o
     $(CXX) -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 program2.o -o program2

#
# We can generalize the creation of the object file.
%.o: %.cc
     $(CXX) -c -Wall -Werror -std=c++11 $*.cc

clean:
     $(RM) *.o *.exe
```

Answer (score 0):

The "make" utility has many rules to simplify  standard build. Compact version can of the Makefile will be:

```
PROGRAMS = program1 program2

all: $(PROGRAMS)

CXXFLAGS=-Wall -Werror -std=c++11 

# Link program1 with the gtest library
program1: LDLIBS=-lgtest

clean:
     $(RM) $(PROGRAMS) *.o

# Following section is needed only for binaries that need more than one object.
# Does not apply in the this case, since program1 depends only on program1.o.
# Included for allow extending the makefile.

program3: program3.o second.o # Additional objects here.
```